# No puedo cargar los datos de mi respuesta del objeto de node api (json) a una tabla HTML con fetch

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, json, fetch

Este es el objeto que entrega la api en la consola y *quisiera poder cargarlos en mi tabla solo logre cargarlos modificando el servidor, pero me gustaria poder obtener otra forma ya que si altero el servidor* **nodejs tendría que alterar toda la aplicacion CRUD de otro sistema.**

Este es el objeto de la consola:

```
{
  "userConsult": [{
    "_id": "649717699eb0bf2121a1e8d0",
    "user": "SirElll",
    "nombres": "nelson",
    "apellidos": "escobar",
    "cedula": 15780693,
    "telefono": 4124824584,
    "email": "keynereduardo@gmail.com",
    "password": "$2a$10$dhLmzdWVBbXMslV30MNnpuOyffkCRQpoyvQopjuMQZcV2PZkoVaYK",
    "createdAt": "2023-06-24T16:18:49.755Z",
    "updatedAt": "2023-06-24T16:18:49.755Z",
    "__v": 0
  }]
}
```

**Este es el frontend pero no recoje los datos de la app para pintarlos en la tabla.**

A continuación les muestro el documento **HTML**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Uso de Fetch</title>

    <style>
      body{
        background-color: cornflowerblue;
      }
      table thead {
            background:#302b63;
            color:white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container mt-4 shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="data">
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
      let url = 'http://localhost:3000/api';
        fetch(url)
            .then( response => response.json() )
            .then( data => mostrarData(data) )
            .catch( error => console.log(error) )

        const mostrarData = (data) => {
            console.log(data)
            let body = ""
            for (var i = 0; i <data.length; i++) {      
               body+=`<tr><td>${data[i]._id}</td><td>${data[i].user}</td><td>${data[i].email}</td></tr>`
            }
            document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = body
            //console.log(body)
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: amigo muchisimas gracias por apoyarme pero sigue igual por que el objeto que retorna es ```{"userConsult": [{}]} lo que no logro es pintar en la tabla los datos la unica forma que lo he hecho es si el objeto no contiene la respuesta res.send({userConsult})entre llaves. Asi es que me los pinta res.send(userConsult) y necesito que sea con el que contiene llaves

Comment: Entiendo, adjunté una respuesta, a ver si me dejé entender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que obtienes es un objeto con un array de objetos como valor del atributo `userConsult`, lo que tienes que hacer es, antes del `for`, acceder al atributo
`userConsult`:

```
const userConsult = data.userConsult;
```

Y luego acceder a los valores de los atributos de cada elemento del atributo `userConsult`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < userConsult.length; i++) {      
  body += `<tr><td>${userConsult[i]._id}</td><td>${userConsult[i].user}</td><td>${userConsult[i].email}</td></tr>`
}
```

#### Ejemplo:

```js
let data = {
  "userConsult": [{
    "_id": "649717699eb0bf2121a1e8d0",
    "user": "SirElll",
    "nombres": "nelson",
    "apellidos": "escobar",
    "cedula": 15780693,
    "telefono": 4124824584,
    "email": "keynereduardo@gmail.com",
    "password": "$2a$10$dhLmzdWVBbXMslV30MNnpuOyffkCRQpoyvQopjuMQZcV2PZkoVaYK",
    "createdAt": "2023-06-24T16:18:49.755Z",
    "updatedAt": "2023-06-24T16:18:49.755Z",
    "__v": 0
  }]
};

const mostrarData = (data) => {
  // console.log(data)
  const userConsult = data.userConsult;
  let body = ""
  for (var i = 0; i < userConsult.length; i++) {      
    body += `<tr><td>${userConsult[i]._id}</td><td>${userConsult[i].user}</td><td>${userConsult[i].email}</td></tr>`
  }
  document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = body
  // console.log(body)
}

mostrarData(data);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

table thead {
  background: #302b63;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container mt-4 shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="data">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: **excelente explicacion mi amigo** muchas gracias por el aporte me sirvio bastante queria saber como resolver esa interrogante. :D

Comment: @NelsonEscobar Si el aporte de alguien te sirvió para solucionar la pregunta y no tienes más comentarios al respecto, es recomendable que categorizes la respuesta como _”aceptada”_, dándole al _check_ que aparee abajo de los votos.

Comment: excelente :D...